# Julia Array to a String (or more complex counter)

Tags: julia

I’m trying to count things in a Julia list with the goal of plotting a histogram. These things may be other arrays to simpler objects like Strings or Integers. My function is currently using the counter library, which works great for non-complex objects like strings or integers.

```
function viz(data::Vector)
    counts = counter(data)
    k = [x for x in keys(counts)]
    v = [x for x in values(counts)]
    bar(k, v./sum(v))
end
```

In Python, I’d just do `str(x) for x in the_list` To convert the inner element to strings, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to do this in Julia.

Or is there a better way to count complex objects in Julia? (I’m a beginner at Julia)

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish this. What kind of complex objects do you have in mind, can you give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[string(x) for x in the_list]
# or
[String(x) for x in the_list]
```

one of them probably gives what you want

Comment: Actually the key for me was to run string() on the keys after running the structure through the counter, not on the original list, but this helped me get there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `StatsBase.countmap(x)`, if it does what you need.

Comment: This had the same issue was counter.